# Securing the whole ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 application

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-authorization

If I want to secure a particular section in my MVC app, I use `[Authorize]` for the ActionMethod. I also know that I can use it for the entire controller so that I don't have to specify it for each and every ActionMethod in it.

I want to require authorization globally and want to be able to allow anonymous users in only a few places. How do I require users to be authorized globally and allow anonymous users in a few ActionMethods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply register `AuthorizeFilter` globally in your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // configure/build your global policy
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                          .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                          .Build();

    services.AddMvc(x => x.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy)));
}
```

(The actual policy-building bits were taken from @Sam's own answer)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer... In `Startup` class, `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()));
            });
        }
```

Comment: Since you marked my answer as correct. I added the relevant part of your policy-builder to my answer as well.